# Information about fields and superfields

Tags: supersymmetry, group-theory, representation-theory, superspace-formalism

I want some explanation of fields and [superfields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superfield) (types and components), and what the relationship between them and representation of a group.

Comment: This is too broad...

Comment: Agreed. Please do ask a more specific question.

Comment: I completely disagree with the close voters who claim this is too broad. Asking about the relationship between the superspace formalism and group representation theory is a very interesting legitimate question, I have never seen this explained in a clear cut way and I am therefore interested in an answer too. Voted to leave open. It would be nice if people who are neither knowledgeable about the superspace formalism nor representation theory could refrain from voting to close this question and leave judgement to other users who are familiar with the topic of the question.Thanks ;-)

Comment: I just want my friends to have an idea about the fields, I am newbie in the level of quantum field theory, thank you